# How does jboss server handles migrated .ear and .war files?

Tags: eclipse, deployment, jboss, war, ear

I am turning to SO here as my last resort, since my situation has been so illogical that I am at my wits end, even google can't get me a relatively close response.

I'll have to be very chronological. I am maintaining an application in Eclipse. The way application changes apply to the website is when I deploy appropriate .ear and .war files in the jboss test server.

I was relatively new to this whole process, so while learning on this, I stumbled upon occurrence I simply cannot logically comprehend.

> 1) I made some changes to the application (let's call it **changeset_1**
>   for convenience), created appropriate .ear and .war files, deployed
>   them to the jboss server.

2) Website was returning error 500. No biggie, I thought, let's deploy working files back to server. It returned the same error as if I
didn't deploy originals at all.

> 3) Restarting jboss server did not accomplish anything.

4) Frustrated, I thought of creating alternate files from the latest deployment directory. So I stored working project directory in the folder neighboring workspace folder used by eclipse. Then I started a new instance of Eclipse, and name new folder as a main namespase (old instance still uses old namespace folder).

> 5) In a new instance, I did not do any changes, I was just following
>   the same steps as before to create appropriate .ear and .war files and
>   deployed them as is to the server.

**Now here is an interesting part**

After performing steps above, I went to the test site link, and what I saw was: **All changes from changeset_1 which I made originally in the first step successfully applied!** At the same time, my last deployment was completely ignored.

*Can anyone please point me in the right direction on how to approach such situation?* Do I miss some kind of fundamental understanding on how all this stuff operates?

I literally don't have any more place to turn to... Unless I could not comprehend such incident to the point I could not explain it properly to google and it was giving me wrong results. Any help is really appreciated!

PS: I will do my best to provide any additional details if needed.

## IMPORTANT EDIT

I initially thought I might've missed or misunderstood something, so I have recreated the scenario above for the second time. And for the second time I got the same outcome. Which no longer makes it an accident, but persistent occurrence.

## EDIT 2

Upon request, here is a full error log in log file

```
2016-10-20 08:11:34,492 WARN
[org.jboss.detailed.classloader.ClassLoaderManager] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1)
Unexpected error during load of:gov.ca.chp.cvs.struts.forms.CVSForm
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:63)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:572)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:532)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:530)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:507)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:134)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:131)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:452)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:251)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:150)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:265)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1119)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:798)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:441)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:299)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at org.apache.struts.config.FormBeanConfig.formBeanClass(FormBeanConfig.java:358)
    at org.apache.struts.config.FormBeanConfig.createActionForm(FormBeanConfig.java:212)
    at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.createActionForm(RequestUtils.java:292)
2016-10-20 08:11:34,492 WARN
[org.jboss.detailed.classloader.ClassLoaderManager] 
(http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) Unexpected error during load of:gov.ca.chp.cvs.struts.forms.CVSForm
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:63)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:572)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:532)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:530)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:507)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:134)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:131)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:452)
```

Comment: Original problem was http 500 error? Can you check the jboss logs? If you paste the full error message here, someone can try to help.

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy Included full log

Comment: You can refer my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rootcause:** "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file" comes when you **compile** a Java class in **higher version** of Java Compiler and **run** it on **lower version** of JRE.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/bad-version-number-in-class-files-cause.html#ixzz4NjV9ORkF

Comment: Thank you, I will read the article. But how does it relate to the phenomenon I am experiencing with migrating files?

Comment: So, you don't want to read that link and don't want to solve your java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError, good.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot read it right now due to my Internet policy I have right now. What confuses me is that after pushing originals for the second time, all changes from first changeset are applied successfully, even though in both eclipse instances they were compiled under the same version. If it was the same behavior for both cases, then I would definitely focus on resolving that error. But this is not the case, which is why I need to understand the approach here.

Comment: All the best Vadzim.

Comment: Your answer did not directly answered why the phenomenon I experienced happened, but because of your answer, I was able to get a hint in the right direction, and thus, was able to resolve the problem. I will accept your answer for pointing me in the right direction.